# Visual Basic Forms: how to make a button click interrupt a previous button click?

Tags: vb.net

Say i press button1 and this starts an infinite while loop. How do i make it so that if  button2 is pressed, it will pause the current action and do the code inside button2 firs before carrying on with the process in button1?

Comment: Try looking into [asynchronous programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/), but... if the "current action" can be paused, and then resumed, then you need to somehow track and toggle that state, and consider how you can implement the resume or retry mechanism and track what "step" you're at. I would warmly recommend elevating the abstraction level a bit, and move all that logic out of a `Button.Click` handler and into a separate `SomeActionCommand` class. And then the handler runs the command (async!) and it's a simple one-liner =)

Answer (score 1):

If the first button really is in an infinite loop, you can't. You might be able to make a button that would interrupt other code, but the event handler for that button can't ever fire because the first button is preventing your app from processing event messages.

So be careful not to create infinite (or even long-running) event handlers (of *any* type) on the default/UI thread.

Comment: So say I was making a game in windows forms, where should I put my game loop?

Comment: In Windows Forms? You wouldn't write a game loop; you'd use timers or similar to push events into the UI, and you'd make sure no method ever ran for longer than about 100ms. If you really needed something long-running, you'd use a BackgroundWorker control.